# JPA: Removing all entities of an OneToMany relationship with a JoinTable

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In my Spring/MySql system, I have some Jpa entities that are joined in a OneToMany relationship via a joinTable on the parent relationship. In this case one Post with many Comments.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "post_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "post_comments",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "comment_id")
    )
    @OrderBy("date ASC")
    private List<Comment> scores = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id","date","value"},callSuper = false)
public class Comment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "comment_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private LocalDate date;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;
}
```

If I then try to delete the Post entity, the issue I have is that the generated SQL tries to delete the comments while they are still in the join table triggering a foreign key violation.

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute batch; SQL [delete from comment where comment_id=?]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:296)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ci_cadreon_reach_optimization`.`post_comments`, CONSTRAINT `fk_post_comments_comment_id` FOREIGN KEY (`comment_id`) REFERENCES `comment` (`comment_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDAT)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

What is the proper way to:

1. delete the join table entry
2. delete the join table left side parent relationship entity
3. delete the join table right side child relationship entities

Some things to keep in mind:

1. There are other entities that have comments via oneToMany relationships, but a comment is not shared among entities.
2. That is the reason the relation is made via a join table as opposed to putting the ID of the post directly on the comment.

I am going to try removing the comments from the collection on the Post side and then saving to see if that functions as a workaround but would like to automate this via JPA configuration if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling `post.getComments().clear()`, saving the post, and *then* deleting the post is the process that works for me (please do let me know if there is a better way!).

I believe that, when a @JoinTable is present the only way to tell Hibernate to first remove the join table entries and then remove the entities is to remove the elements from the list and save that operation.

The parent child items can then be removed separately, either by Cascade or manually.